# Yellow background for Stack Exchange icon in Winter Bash 2017 logo is too distracting

Tags: feature-request, design, logo, winter-bash-2017

The logo of [Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) looks like this:

[image]

I find the yellow background very distracting, and I even clicked it expecting a menu or at least some link. But it's just part of the logo.

Can this please be changed same way it always was, transparent and less intrusive? e.g.  previous year this was the logo:

[image]

Comment: I agree it looks distracting, but I don't care enough to ask for a change.

Comment: It's actually a moon :(

Comment: Winterbash hater found ...

Comment: @rene no no, on the contrary: I do this out of love to Winter Bash! ;)

Comment: After turning off all the lights in the windows I really wanted to be able to turn off the moon... just sayin...

Comment: What do you get if you live South of the Equator?

Comment: @Bathsheba probably the same, sun is also yellow. They made is cross timezones! :D

Comment: Hats! Hats! Hats!

Comment: @Snow your name surely fits!

Comment: Winter is coming....

Comment: @Snow append Jon to your name and it will become real...

Comment: @rene I think you mean "hatter".

Comment: @Catija but I'm not Mad. Yet. :D

Comment: It's a cheeseburger superimposed on a yellow moon. Very Christmassy and Winter Holidayee

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The icon is a subtle purple.

It just happens to sit right in front of the full moon. Think of it as the Stack Exchange version of this:

[image: the Winter Bash logo, but instead of the Stack Exchange icon there is the famous bicycle with Elliott and E.T.]